# Even after installation of Ubuntu 22.04, its work and look like previous version (20.04)?

Tags: 20.04, upgrade, 22.04

I have upgraded my Ubuntu installation from 20.04 to 22.04. After installation it still looks like the previous version, 20.04. I do not have any of the features for Ubuntu 22.04.

[image]

How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: Your picture shows Ubuntu-MATE and not Ubuntu.  You're using the MATE desktop & not GNOME used by Ubuntu.

Comment: But if I made guest login, It shows all the features of upgraded ubuntu 22.04.

Comment: You *possibly* have more than one desktop installed; thus you need to select which you're using for the session; a different user (inc. *guest*) can have a different default/last-used desktop/WM to another user.

Comment: You have not specified any particular problem. The screenshot shows 22.04; you installed 22.04; you have 22.04. So what's the problem? MATE is a very mature stable desktop, as it's just a fork of GNOME 2, which is some 20+ years old. There *isn't* much difference between MATE v1.24 in 20.04 and MATE 1.26.1 in 22.04.